# Is there a way to get children element while using Selenium in javascript?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, dom

I want to adapt the script I use in Javascript to Selenium(javascript). I tried for a long time but couldn't find the solution.
[I want to explain my question on this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7dvV.png)

```
await chromeDriver.findElement(By.id("nav-search-submit-button")).click();
```

When I use the above code driver finds the element and click function works.

```
await chromeDriver.findElement(By.id("nav-search-submit-text").children[0]).click();
```

Then i try to find children element with above code driver can not find children element but chrome console finds element on website. I would appreciate it if you could help me find the children element using Selenium in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium doesn't have a `children` property. You have to do another `findElement()` from the parent.

```
await chromeDriver.findElement(By.id("nav-search-submit-text"))
    .findElements(By.xpath("./child::*"))[0].click();
```

You could also use `.findElement()`, which will only return the first match, so you don't need to use `[0]`.

Comment: I tried what you said but it didn't work.

Comment: Thanks for help, i learned how to use xpath. It's better than children node.